# The !is_numeric function in PHP does not accept NULL VALUE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to validate a certain input wherein the user could just input integer values... otherwise an error message will be executed

```
$user_mcc = $_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'];
if($user_mcc == ""){
    is_numeric($_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode']);
}

if (!is_numeric($_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'])){

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Not a numeric value!\n\nMake sure that your country codes, area codes\nand mobile/fax/phone numbers are correct! \n"); return true;</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">history.back();</script>'; 
    die('' . mysql_error());



}
```

I've tried so many functions like `empty` , `is_null` , `== NULL` , `== 'NULL` and so on... but it didn't work.

If I put a string value to the input text field like let's say I input... `"Banana"` , the `!is_numeric` function above can be executed because the inputted value is `FALSE` and not a numeric value.

But, whenever I leave the input field empty which is `NULL`, the `!is_numeric` function can be still executed, like it recognizes a `NULL` value as not a numeric value. What can I do to bypass `!is_numeric` function if the input value is `NULL`. Thank you.

**PS:** I already tried `!is_int` , `!is_integer` and `ctype_digit` , but goes to same result, it did not accept **NULL** values.

Comment: How about `!is_numeric($_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode']) && $_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'] !== NULL`

Comment: @Lex How can I swap? Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out.

I find this post helpful: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml . For those who are struggling for same issue you may use Javascript for validation.

Comment: @xirukitepe You still need to validate the values server-side as well; JavaScript can easily be turned off, or even altered. The only trustworthy validation is on the server itself. Don't trust values that have been "validated" by JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's probably because `null` **isn't** a numeric value. It's void; it's nothing, and it certainly doesn't equal the integer 0. If you want to check for a numeric value, or null, then that's exactly what you should do:

```
if( $yourvalue !== null && !is_numeric( $yourvalue ) ) {
}
```

Comment: You should test for `null` before calling `is_numeric`

Comment: @Florent The operator in between is `&&`, which means both sides will be executed regardless of the outcome of the first statement. So no, there's no point in swapping them, other than micro-optimalisation.

Comment: @BerryLangerak That is totally wrong. That is *not at all* what && means; it only executes the second half if the first half is true. The order of arguments is often *extremely* important, and it is absolutely not a micro-optimization.

Comment: @Florent @meagar Gah, must've had a brainfart that day. `if( false && call( ) )` will never call, you guys are obviously right. Switched the order.

Answer (score 0):

I think , it's work with this code :

```
$isNumeric = false;
// Verify your var exist
if (isset($_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'])){    
    // if var exist, you create $user_mcc
    $user_mcc = $_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'];

    // test empty and null values [ == if(!empty($user_mcc) ]
    if (("" != $user_mcc) && ( NULL != $user_mcc)){
        // if value is not NULL and not empty test if value is numeric...
        if (is_numeric($user_mcc)){
            // Your value is Numeric
            $isNumeric = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After, if your value is not a numeric value you can use $isNumeric boolean :

```
if (!$isNumeric){ // [ == if ( $user_mcc is not numeric ^^ ) ]
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Not a numeric value!\n\nMake sure that your country codes, area codes\nand mobile/fax/phone numbers are correct! \n"); return true;</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">history.back();</script>'; 
    die('' . mysql_error());
}
```

Fore more sample, or details, you can read [this](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-numeric.php) page of Php.net ( they are many samples)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
function is_numeric_not_null($var) {
    return(($var != "") && ($var != NULL) && is_numeric($var));
}

$user_mcc = $_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'];

if (!is_numeric_not_null($user_mcc)){

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Not a numeric value!\n\nMake sure that your country codes, area codes\nand mobile/fax/phone numbers are correct! \n"); return true;</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">history.back();</script>'; 
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$user_mcc = empty($_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode']) ? null : $_REQUEST['mobile_countrycode'];

if (null === $user_mcc || !is_numeric($user_mcc)) {
    // Not a numeric value
}
```